# Minimum height for each cell HTML table

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I've got a table with 3 cells and 1 row. I get the text to show in the cells out of a database, and my question is: How can I use a minimum height for all three cells? So they're not all the same height. As the middle column will be a bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells in the same row are always of same height, the height of the tallest one.

- Do nothing and it's fine
- If you want cell widths to adapt somewhat so that cells with a lot of content are wider than others and less tall, then remove `table-layout: fixed` from parent table (by default it's not there)
- `min-height` won't work in tables, you'll have to use `height` property here
- you can adjust padding (internal margins) for better styling: `th, td { padding: 4px 6px; }`. Margins won't have any effect on cells (if cells aren't collapsed with `border-collapse`, then you can use `border-spacing` ... or padding) but `table` is still affected by margin as a whole of course

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS:

```
td { height: 100px }
```

A table cell will expand if there's more content.